# Half-installed Windows 7, how to restore Windows XP bootloader

Tags: mbr, windows-installation

I was going to install Windows 7 on my old pc, however I decided against it half way through the installation (just after first reboot) and I cancelled it. Then I worked out that I can press `F8` then press `ESC` and choose `Previous Windows Installation` and I can boot into Windows XP.

However whenever I turn off the computer normally, it tries to start installing Windows 7 again; however if I hibernate the computer, it boots into Windows XP fine.

So my question is; How can I restore it so it always boots into Windows XP, instead of Windows 7 Install.

EDIT: I don't have the Windows Install Disc, Unless there is a way to get the Windows recovery console on a flash drive, that wont work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, the most easy solution will be to start the repair console from a Windows XP CD and perform a [fixmbr](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/bootcons_fixmbr.mspx?mfr=true) and a [fixboot](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/bootcons_fixboot.mspx?mfr=true). That should reinstall your WinXP bootloader, which is not able to start Windows 7.

Comment: I don't have the Windows XP disc any more.

Comment: You can use the UBCD (Ultimate boot cd), which includes tools for rewriting the mbr and the booloader. http://www.ubcd4win.com/
Feature list: http://www.ubcd4win.com/contents.htm see the topic "-partition"

Comment: I'll try this when I get home.